# Ban links to postimage.org

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter, content-blocklist

So recently, I have seen images linked from [`postimage.org`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postimage.org) (an image hosting site) used in questions. Often times, the OP doesn't post their code in the question, but just links it to the website.

**But, there is something much worse than just OPs being lazy and posting images of their code to the website `postimage.org`.**  The website itself hosts the images fine, why I am proposing a ban is the following: **when displaying the images, the website often displays it alongside of inappropriate ads, which honestly nobody wants to see.**  [Simply searching for "postimage.org" on SO will yield questions/answers that link to the website.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postimage.org)

> The bigger picture is for OPs not to link images of their code from
>   external websites.  For now, I propose banning any link with
>   `postimage.org` in it.

Comment: So what about [questions that are asking about postimage.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314667/postimage-org-upload-image-codes)? #sarcasm

Comment: @TinyGiant that is not exposing people to malicious ad content, so I figure by the reason that I am asking for the ban it would be ok.   Questions about postimage.org really shouldn't exist because if they do, they would be too broad (like the one you linked).

Comment: I know, that's why I voted to close it. That was just the first question that came up in the search so I thought I would have some fun with it.

Comment: Posting code as an image instead of a formatted code block is already a problem that I think could warrant action to be taken against it if it's happening on a regular basis.

Comment: What's worse than OP posting questions is answers that are essentially just a link to `postimage.org`. Those need DVs.

Comment: any question that posts images with only a link get an automatic downvote, and that postimage.org site is blocked by most corporate firewalls most likely.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Yes, a downvote, and either a flag as NAA or closing as "neccessary info must be *in the question itself*", depending on it being an answer/question.

Comment: I suppose I've spent too much time on the Internet, but when I finally found a working, non-direct link to a hosted image (they seem to only pop up on SO every few months, if that), the ads seemed pretty ordinary - clickbait titles with clickbait photos of women (usually in ordinary outfits, occasionally in bikinis). Oh, except for this one ad with a picture of a spider which was absolutely horrifying because spiders. I would agree with banning spiders.

Comment: Ban because ads... or [adblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)?

Comment: I also don't think "which honestly nobody wants to see" is quite accurate, as many people want to see attractive women (photos of which comprise most of those ads). In other words, I was more than happy to conduct this research.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts do you think everyone has adblock? Do you think everyone who doesn't log in has adblock?

Comment: @intboolstring I think if the issue is that "nobody wants to see ads" then the solution isn't to ban a domain name that's barely even an issue, but for the users who are bothered by ads to just deal with the problem directly and install an ad blocker.

Comment: Totally agree with blocking psotimage.org.  There is absolutely no need to permit users to post images on sites other than the one that stackoverflow itself provides to its users - imgur.  Especially since those are advertisement riddled, and javascript warning you about navigating away from viewing those unwanted advertisements.  Sure, I could adblock, but that shouldn't be necessary when I'm trying to assist a user with a question.

Comment: There are **a lot** of question which are links to an image screenshot (imgur) or directly embed. There should be a warning for new users clicking on "insert image".

Comment: @KeyszerS imgur is not the only image hosting site in existence, and even if SO provides support for using imgur, that shouldn't necessarily disallow other hosts from being used. If your argument is that "imgur is the only host we officially support, so let's ban postimage", then that opens up an argument for all hosts besides imgur, which is ridiculous. There are plenty of valid hosting sites that are as easy or more easy to use than imgur. For example in some of my questions, I use [puu.sh](http://puush.me/) because it has an application for directly uploading screenshots on my computer.

Comment: My point is, if we ban postimage for this reason, that is a slippery slope to banning even valid hosting sites for the same reason. Instead of banning image hosts, we should be focusing on the key issue, which is penalizing users for uploading screenshots of plaintext code. Let's not allow this issue to ban symptoms of the underlying problem.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, the problem with third party image hosting services is that they might not be around for long and then the question or answers will become less useful.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the ads... *But* I do think it's awful practice to post an image of code. I can only hope I'd be excessively downvoted if I uploaded a screenshot of code for a question or answer. Using postimage.org doesn't seem any different.

Comment: postImage is a good site. I don't see the issue – unless it is to make an issue out of nothing.

Comment: People also seem to be asking / answering legitimate web questions, where their code uses links to the website: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055582/css-limited-background-repeat-multiple-background-images/8055840#8055840) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608884/how-do-i-scale-this-layout)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu _technically_, imgur is a 3rd party service for SO as well. Nobody can say with any confidence whether one hosting service will last longer than another. You take that risk regardless of which service you choose.

Comment: If users post images of code, then that should be sufficient reason to close the question, regardless of the site on which those images are hosted.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, Stack Overflow has a dedicated Imgur account. It seems to me that they use Imgur more like some sort of CDN. Also Stack Overflow would probably have a backup plan if their Imgur account closes.